# Scheduling Facebook posts for future

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am developing an application by which we can schedule our posts for future & which will be automatically posted to facebook on scheduled time.

I am able to post when I am logged in to facebook using my web application but I have no idea how will i post on scheduled time when i am not logged in to the facebook.

How will facebook identify that post should be posted on my wall & not on others wall.
Can any one help me.

I am using c#, asp.net for my application.

Comment: Did you had a look on the facebook SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a facebook application using the Facebook API, you will then add that application your account providing it with the ability to post to your wall.

Then simply have the application check a database with your pre written content in, and when it's time post the content.

Have a look at the getting started guide: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

If more than one person is using the application then there will a public token saved in the database assigned to each user, which facebook will authenticate against to see if that token/app has permission to post to that particular users wall.

Comment: Yes it will do like this only but if two persons have scheduled post for same time then how will app & facebook will identify that which post to posted where ? For that there should be something extra which will identify both persons.

Comment: Well the other person would also add the application, and the facebook user token that you will get to identify yourself. Check the last bit of my answer regarding this.

Comment: @vaibhavshah why did you unmark as an answer? Anything wrong?